# Python - Creating generic functions for unspecified input

Tags: python

I would like to be able to have this program print out an answer that says something like 'Sorry I dont recognize that input' if the user types anything other than 1-5.

```
import time
rating=input()
if rating == '1':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Well, you mustve just had a bad day.')
if rating =='2':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Second to last means I wasnt even the best at losing...')
if rating =='3':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Atleast thats almost passing.')
if rating =='4':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Im offended.')
if rating =='5':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Well yeah, obviously.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `if`, `elif` and `else` where if the input is anything except 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, the `else` in the code will print the message you want to be displayed. The code below also will prevent checking all the other numbers because of the `elif`. In your code, you were checking all the numbers in 5 if statements.

```
import time
rating=input()
if rating == '1':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Well, you mustve just had a bad day.')
elif rating =='2':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Second to last means I wasnt even the best at losing...')
elif rating =='3':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Atleast thats almost passing.')
elif rating =='4':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Im offended.')
elif rating =='5':
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Well yeah, obviously.')
else:
    print ('Sorry I dont recognize that input')
```

**Asking the user again until the correct number is entered** (based on your comment below)

```
while rating:
    if rating == '1':
        time.sleep(.5)
        print('Well, you mustve just had a bad day.')
        break
    elif rating =='2':
        time.sleep(.5)
        print('Second to last means I wasnt even the best at losing...')
        break
    elif rating =='3':
        time.sleep(.5)
        print('Atleast thats almost passing.')
        break
    elif rating =='4':
        time.sleep(.5)
        print('Im offended.')
        break
    elif rating =='5':
        time.sleep(.5)
        print('Well yeah, obviously.')
        break
    else:
        print ('Sorry I dont recognize that input. Enter the rating again.')
        rating=input()
        continue
```

**Output (second case)**

```
6
Sorry I dont recognize that input. Enter the rating again.
6
Sorry I dont recognize that input. Enter the rating again.
5
Well yeah, obviously.
```

Comment: By 30s bravo :)

Comment: I hate to ask this here but theres a 90 minute post limit. How might I go about allowing the user to have another chance at typing their rating after the else condition is met? Besides, of course, copy pasting the code many times over.

Comment: @Ashton: I added this option as well to my answer

Comment: @Bazingaa Wasnt aware the continue function existed, thankyou.